# How to fix merge conflict with this git command?

Tags: git

I have git like this:

- `git clone https://github.com/coderbyte-org/big-o`
- `cd big-o`
- `git checkout -b feature/branch-a`
- `echo "This contents is beginning" > file.txt`
- `git add file.txt`
- `git commit -m "docs: add file.txt"`
- `git checkout -b feature/branch-b`
- `echo "This is new content." > file.txt`
- `git add file.txt`
- `git commit -m "docs: update file.txt"`
- `git checkout feature/branch-a`
- `echo "This is another content" > file.txt`
- `git merge feature/branch-b`
- `git show HEAD:file.txt && git show --pretty='' HEAD^1`

I always got

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    file.txt
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

How to resolve the merge conflict by keeping the changes in `feature/branch-b` ?

Comment: There are no conflicts, you just need to commit or stash before you can merge the branches

Comment: What mousetail wrote. That's either `git commit` or `git stash` you need to run.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+Your+local+changes+to+the+following+files+would+be+overwritten+by+merge%3A

Comment: @Friedrich @mousetail

if I add this 

`git add file.txt`
`git commit -m "add"`


i got error

`Aborting commit due to empty commit message.
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
 file.txt
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
`

Comment: That does not look right. Are you using `-m` or `-M`? Cause it **has** to be `-m`.... or just use no `-m` and let it go into the editor, set a nice message, save and exit and the commit will be done.

Comment: You may have a merge in progress, run `git merge --abort` to cancel any running merges

Comment: Please [edit] and add the output of `git status`.